# Can't recover ubuntu partition with testdisk

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I am trying to recover my Ubuntu partition from my ssd. I don't know why it can't be detected by neither gparted nor the grub recovery shell (unknown filesystem for all hard discs). I tried to recover the partition with TestDisk from a live USB stick (scanning for Intel and EFI GPT) with quick and deep search, but none were found.

The problem appeared after installing a new ssd for windows (windows and ubuntu are on separate hard drives).

Is there anything else I can try to recover the partition table, or at least some of the data?

Comment: The drive seems to be defective. Replace it. That the "problem appeared after installing a new ssd" is either a coincidence or a consequence of something else.